# How to reference a one-to-one model in sails-filemaker?

Tags: sails.js, filemaker

I have two models. Staff and Role. I am using the sails-filemaker adapter.
Each staff member has a primary role which is linked up correctly in the filemaker database. The question is how to get the role attributes showing when referencing a staff member.

Given

Staff:

```
/**
* Staff.js
*
* @description :: Staff employed by the business
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

module.exports = {

    connection: 'filemaker',
    tableName: 'staff-list-api-layout',

    autoPK:false ,
    autoCreatedAt: false ,
    autoUpdatedAt: false ,

  attributes: {
        id: {
            columnName: 'staff_id_',
            type: 'integer',
            primaryKey: true,
            unique:true
        } , 
        roleId:{
            columnName: 'role_id',
            type: 'integer',
            foreignKey: true
        },
        role: {
            model: 'role',
            unique: true
        } ,
        name:{
            columnName:'full_name',
            type: 'string'
        },
        createdAt:{
            type:'date'
        },
        updatedAt:{
            type:'date'
        }
  }

};
```

Role:

```
/**
* Role.js
*
* @description :: Roles that employees can have
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

module.exports = {

    connection: "filemaker",
    tableName: 'roles-api-layout',

    autoPK:false ,
    autoCreatedAt: false ,
    autoUpdatedAt: false ,

  attributes: {
        id: {
            columnName: 'role_id_',
            type: 'integer',
            primaryKey: true
        }, 
        role: {
            type: 'string'
        }, 
        timesheetSort: {
            columnName:'timesheet_sort',
            type: 'integer'
        }, 
        createdAt: {
            type: 'date'
        }, 
        updatedAt: {
            type: 'date'
        }
  }

};
```

where

http://192.168.1.71:6366/role/1 returns

```
{
  "role": "Artist",
  "createdAt": "2016-09-20T07:27:12.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2016-09-20T07:27:22.000Z",
  "modid": "5",
  "recid": "1",
  "id": 1,
  "timesheetSort": 1
}
```

and

http://192.168.1.71:6366/staff/3 returns

```
{
  "createdAt": "2016-06-20T08:31:03.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2016-06-20T09:22:49.000Z",
  "staff_role::role": "Artist.",
  "modid": "15",
  "recid": "28",
  "id": 3,
  "roleId": 1,
  "name": "David"
}
```

What would I have to change in the models to get

```
{
  "createdAt": "2016-06-20T08:31:03.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2016-06-20T09:22:49.000Z",
  "modid": "15",
  "recid": "28",
  "id": 3,
  "roleId": 1,
  "role" :  {
      "role": "Artist",
      "createdAt": "2016-09-20T07:27:12.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2016-09-20T07:27:22.000Z",
      "modid": "5",
      "recid": "1",
      "id": 1,
      "timesheetSort": 1
  } ,
  "name": "David"
}
```

from http://192.168.1.71:6366/staff/3 ?

Answer (score 0):

instead defining "role" attribute use this in your staff model:

```
role: {model: 'role'}
```

You can look up on modules assosiations

Comment: Thanks, Keith. I saw him mentioning feathers on tweeter.